# Detecting whether last dimension is 1 or 5 in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing TensorFlow (python) logic to determine if the last dimension of a tensor is either 1 or 5. This expression should be false if the tensor is a scalar. The shape of the tensor is unknown at graph construction time.

Given tensor `input`, I have tried

```
tf.logical_and(
  # The tensor must not be a scalar.
  tf.greater(tf.rank(input), 0),
  # Check the last dimension.
  tf.logical_or(
    tf.equal(tf.shape(input)[-1], 1),
    tf.equal(tf.shape(input)[-1], 5)
  )
)
```

However, this logic raises an error when the `input` tensor is a scalar because the `tf.greater(tf.rank(input), 0)` portion of the expression fails to cause TensorFlow to short-circuit (and avoid executing the `tf.logical_or` portion of the graph). This is expected behavior.

Is there any way that I could find the last dimension of a tensor but have the logic gracefully handle the case in which the input tensor is a scalar?

Maybe for instance there is a way to enforce a control dependency that causes the check for rank to run first?

I think I could use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) here, but I am a little uneasy about how calling a lambda function could change the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply expand the dims of input tensor to make it work in all cases (i.e. converting the scalar case to a tensor):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
input_expanded = tf.expand_dims(input, axis=0)
last_dim_size = tf.shape(input_expanded)[-1]

result_tensor = tf.logical_and(
    # The tensor must not be a scalar.
    tf.greater(tf.rank(input_expanded) - 1, 0),
    # Check the last dimension.
    tf.logical_or(
        tf.equal(last_dim_size, 1),
        tf.equal(last_dim_size, 5)
    )
)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for input_value in [1, np.zeros((2,)), np.zeros((1, 5)), np.zeros((1, 2, 6))]:
        result = sess.run(result_tensor, feed_dict={input: input_value})
        print('Input: {}'.format(input_value))
        print('Output: {}'.format(result))
        print()
```

Output:

```
Input: 1
Output: False

Input: [ 0.  0.]
Output: False

Input: [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Output: True

Input: [[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]]
Output: False
```

Answer (score 0):

In TF2 you can simply use `.shape` and check whether the last (`[-1]`) dimension is any of the dimensions you're looking for. You don't have to run a session because eager execution is enabled by default in version 2.

```py
some_tensor.shape[-1] in [1, 5]
```

colab demo: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L4XD04XBuPSBeaB7Bb-twpHJCyYPkZrt